# compareWith does not select

Tags: angular, typescript, compare

I have a select option with compareWith but it is not selecting the record in the dropdown list.

```
<select class="form-control"  name="selectAnswer" [(ngModel)]="Result.answers[i]" [compareWith]="compareFn">
<option [ngValue]="answer" *ngFor="let answer of QuestionOption.Answers">{{answer.description}}</option>
```

So I have one object Result.answers[i] where i have within an array my selected and saved values (previously saved when creating the record.

In the QuestionOption.Answers I have for all potential Answers for the related question.

Now in the compareFn I compare QuestionOption.Answers with Result.answers[i].

```
compareFn(c1: any, c2: any): boolean {
      console.log(c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2);
         return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
    }
```

in the console.log I receive true, false, false ...
So it seems the function returns perfectly fine if c1.id === c2.id

BUT
in the dropdownlist the record is not selected. It just stays empty.

What do I miss?

Everything seems fine except the selection is not working. What could be the root cause?

Comment: No sorry, this was a typo during copy of the code to stackoverflow

Comment: I found this: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

and there they reference to: Note: We listen to the 'change' event because 'input' events aren't fired for selects in Firefox and IE.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1024350

I'm using firefox. Is this maybe the root cause of the issue?